# How to make my program check for an installation to have completed and then "come back to life"

Tags: c#, java, c++, automation

I am developing an application for automating the [BVT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_verification_test) process of our product. This product runs on a multitude of platforms and has sorta "submodules" which are installed separately; So it made a sense to `automate` the installation part of BVT (plus automating the `actually` Build verification tests)

Now, I have written java code to do the installations (basically fire a set of commands thru java [runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class).

Now I am working on the actual `tests`. Here, I have come across the following problem:

Once my `installation` program finishes its role, there is a time gap (typically 15-20 mins) in which the installation actually happens. Now, since my boss wishes for `end to end` automation, I cannot break up the process of installation and testing. So my **question** is:

How do I make the second part of the program (testing part) *wait* till the installation part has finished. I mean is there any way I could *poll* and make the second part active as soon as I find (say) the process responsible for installation has exited.

What do you guys suggest ? (That polling is probably a stupid idea .. and I am a noob .. so dont take it too seriously). I am just looking for a solution to this problem in any way possible. Yes, the problem has to be solved thru java and must be available on win + linux platforms.

**EDIT**

I think if you can help me with non java paradigms to solve the problem that will be fine as well, because once i understand what kind of construct can be used here, I can find try to find *something similar* in java.

Comment: Then do not "fire" installation. Multi-thread it and wait until the installers return. For example, in Ant, you can do this using <parallel> task with several nested <exec> or <sshexec> tasks, which will wait until the commands executed return.

Comment: @coolcfan I understand. Thanks, But can you please you please suggest an alternative to using the Ant <parallel> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return 0, I cant understand how you would apply polling .. but ,according to what i have understood ,i think ,you can do it using threads.. I mean,if you use threading, you can add wait() calls before the Test part starts executing..